# How to remove directories I don't have permission to access in Rust?

Tags: rust, filesystems

How to remove a directory recursively in Rust, deleting empty directories with Unix permissions of `000` as well? These permissions are read as "no reading, writing or executing is allowed by any user".

I've previously created the directory like this:

```
mkdir -p dir/trap
chmod 000 dir/trap
```

I've tried this method:

```
std::fs::remove_dir_all("dir").unwrap();
```

It fails with "Permission denied" however. Are there any other solutions that still remove such directory, like `rm -rf` would?

Comment: "Are there any other solutions that ignore the read-only flag?" be root ? You are saying is there a solution to ignore permission in linux... I hope there is none ;)

Comment: @Stargateur: Actually, to delete a file (or directory) in Unix you need write permissions to the parent directory, not to the file itself... except in sticky directories.

Comment: @Stargateur I need something akin to `rm -rf`. Now, `rm -rf` surely does delete "000" directories and their children.

Comment: Actually, I've just tested it in my Linux box and `rm -rf` does **not** delete `000`, non-empty directories. It fails with `EPERM`.

Comment: Oh, indeed. Though it does remove "000" directories if they have no children. Like my latest example above in the question.

Comment: @rodrigo Yes, but I never say that read was needed.

Comment: I cannot think of any way of removing a non-empty directory with `000` mode which does not involved first changing the permissions on the directory to be able to (1) read its content and (2) write to it (so as to delete said content). I'd advise leaving it up to the user (`chmod -R` changes permissions recursively).

Comment: @MatthieuM note that I'm not asking to remove a non-empty directory. I'm basically asking the same behavior of `rm -rf`. It removes **empty** "000" directories, as well as accessible non-empty ones.

Comment: Ah; that's interesting. I wonder if this is an edge case which `remove_dir_all` should cover. That is, if the user does not have the permission to read the directory content, simply attempt to remove it (which will fail if it contains anything). You may want to file a bug against `std::fs::remove_dir_all` and see if the larger Rust community is amenable to the suggestion.

Comment: @MatthieuM I was wondering about that as well. I'll look into it. Thanks for giving some confirmation. P.S. Meanwhile I've made a micro-crate for that.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `remove_dir_all()` first walks the contents of the directory to delete any file or subdirectory that may be there. And you do not have permissions to read the directory, thus the error.

You can call instead:

```
std::fs::remove_dir("dir").unwrap();
```

It does not try to walk the directory, instead assumes that it is already empty, and fails if it is not.

If you want to delete a non-empty, `000` moded directory you will have to change the permissions first back to a sensible value and then you can call `remove_dir_all()` safely.

Comment: [set_permissions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.set_permissions.html) is a possible solution but I believe that it's uncommon for a program to change permission on the file, it's better to let the user fix the problem by using chmod or equivalent.

Comment: The problem is that I want to do it recursively. Like some inner folder can have "000" permissions. I'll update the question. UPD: done, updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

No easy answer was found yet, so I've written my own implementation: https://crates.io/crates/rm_rf

Usage:

```
rm_rf::force_remove_all("target").expect("Failed to remove target");
```

This will remove read-only files on Windows and empty directories lacking read access on Linux.